# File name disappears on INSERT(file upload)

Tags: php, mysql

```
foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key=>$value){
    $ads_table=ads_table;
    $path_to_save_db='ads/'.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $id="60";
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO $ads_table (ad_url)  VALUES ('$path_to_save_db')") or (mysql_error());
}
```

this works fine!
but when i add another column 'id'

```
foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key=>$value){
    $ads_table=ads_table;
    $path_to_save_db='ads/'.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $id="60";
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO $ads_table (id,ad_url)  VALUES ('$id','$path_to_save_db')") or (mysql_error());
}
```

it inserts `id=>60 ad_url=>ads/:no file name:`
how?

Comment: Why would you loop an insert record with a static id?

Comment: Is `ads_table` meant to be a string or is it just a bad constant name?

Comment: i just put all involved in the action for u to see i do not loop them.

Comment: a suggestion. make id an auto increment column and run query without id in it

Comment: i did that and it works,but how its happen?

Comment: add $sql = "INSERT INTO $ads_table (id,ad_url)  VALUES ('$id','$path_to_save_db')"; then print it for dbugging echo $sql . ' ' . mysql_error(); and post the output here

Comment: found the solution,thx everyone an error in sql.